# Is there always an injective linear functional? ($L^*$ surjective $\Rightarrow L$ injective)

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm struggling with the (seemingly straightforward) linear algebra problem that follows:
Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional $\mathbb{ F } $-vector spaces and $L : V \to W$ a linear map.  Define the dual transformation 
$$
 L^* : W^* \to V^*
$$
by 
$$
 L^* (\varphi) (v) = \varphi (L (v))
$$
for $\varphi \in W^*$ and $v \in V$.  Show that if $L^*$ is onto, then $L$ is one-to-one.
Here's my attempt: suppose that $L^*$ is surjective, and let $L (v) = 0$.  We aim to prove that $v =0$.  For every $\varphi \in W^*$ we have 
$$
 L^* (\varphi) (v) = \varphi (L (v)) = 0
$$
Since $L^*$ is assumed to be surjective, for every $\psi \in V^*$ there exists some $\varphi \in W^*$ such that $L^* (\varphi) = \psi$.  It follows that if there exists an injective linear functional $\psi \in V^*$ then we will have the achieved result: suppose that such a $\psi$ exists.  Then there is some $\varphi \in W^*$ such that $L^* (\varphi) = \psi$.  Hence, 
$$
 0 = L^* (\varphi)(v) = \psi (v)
$$
Then $\psi$ injective gives that $v =0$ as desired.
There are a number of possibilities: such a $\psi$ exists but I've not been able to think it up, no such $\psi$ exists and this is the wrong approach, the statement is false.  Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $L(v)=0$ *and* $v\ne0$, then there exists $\psi\in V^*$ such that $\psi(v)\ne0$. Since $L^*$ is surjective, there is $\varphi\in W^*$ such that $L^*(\varphi)=\psi$. In particular
$$
0\ne\psi(v)=L^*(\varphi)(v)=\varphi(L(v))=\varphi(0)=0
$$
a contradiction.

Why does $\psi$ exist? Because any nonzero vector can be completed to a basis.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V,W$ vector spaces of dimensions $n,m$ rispectively. Consider a linear transformation $f:V\longrightarrow W$ and we call $A \in M_{m,n}(\mathbb{F})$ the matrix associate to $f$ respect to the canonical bases. Then is very easy to show the matrix associate to $f^*:W^*\longrightarrow V^*$ is $\text{ }^tA\in M_{n,m}(\mathbb{F})$, respect to the dual bases.

Suppose now $f^*$ is onto; in other words $\text{ }^tA$ has maximal rank; which is equal to $n$. Clearly the rank of $A$ is $n$ since is its transpose; then $rkA=dimV$, then $f$ is injective.